# Is a tag named [messaging] relevant

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup-request

As the title says [messaging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/messaging) as a tag is confusing.

Here is a question that I just saw:
[How to disable Messaging on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1017170/how-to-disable-messaging-on-windows-10)

Comment: I agree this is an overly broad tag.  Some of the tag's posts are about personal communications, others about system/software information displays.  I'm guessing we have other tags that are specific to those subjects.

Comment: This is a classic meta tag, though we'll need to retag some of these and create *proper* tags with exerpts and writeups if needed.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: by meta do you mean it belongs on the metaSU or something else???

Comment: In this case, something else - a tag that's massively broad and not that helpful.

Comment: Tips: when writing a tag name on the title, use `[name-of-tag]` format to make it easier to recognize. Bonus point: [make it puny](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup-request).